# Is there a simpl eway to prevent any row insertions temporarliy in SQL SERVER table?

Tags: sql-server, locking

IS there a simple way to halt (anybody with permissions) inserting new rows in a specific table.

MySql has a lock write command but how can I do similar fin SQL SERVER?

Comment: You can put the database in read-only mode.

Comment: Can you please explain how?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, but you can google "how to put sql server database in read only mode" and find out.

Comment: You can revoke insert/update/delete privileges to the user account that accesses the database or individual table, allowing only select to continue viewing data.

Comment: However, I'm pretty sure readonly mode affects the entire database, and cannot target a single table.

Comment: Yes I want a single table

Answer (score 1):

You could use sp_getapplock & sp_releaseapplock...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx

Another way would be to use TABLOCK in your SELECT...

SELECT ...
  FROM a
  WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following permissions on SQL server table -

1) DENY DELETE ON Customers to Joe, Mary  -- Deny write access to users

2) GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Table1 TO Joe   -- Only select permission is available to Joe

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permission of the table to only be used with 'x' users.

Create different authenticiation levels and then set that to match your tables.

[Edit: My lock in action here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul8eV.png)